# Effecient way to fetch related models count in Django ORM

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

I'm working on Django 1.10 and PostgreSQL9.6

I have two models in my project: Order and Customer. Also I'm using Django's `auth.User` to store login credentials.

Here is a code snipped:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class Order(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='created_orders')
    # ... other fields ...

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # ... other fields ...
```

Now, I need to show a table of `customers` and show a number of orders created by each of them.

The staight forward code is:

```
for customer in Customer.objects.all():
    print(customer.user.created_orders.count())
```

Now I need to avoid N+1 problem and make Django to fetch all data with constant number of queries.

I've tried to write something like:

```
    query = Customer.objects.select_related('user').annotate(
        orders_count=Count('user.created_orders')
    )
```

But this gives me an error like `Cannot resolve keyword 'user.created_orders' into field.`

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *not* use a dot (`.`) here, but two consecutive underscores (`__`):

```
query = Customer.objects.select_related('user').annotate(
    orders_count=Count('user__created_orders')
)
```

Note that you do *not* need to `.select_related('user')` in order to annotate a queryset. If you however plan to use the `.user` later in your logic, it can indeed boost performance.

Comment: I was close to this, but used user__created_orders in select_related instead :D. Thankyou

Comment: @atomAltera: well I had indeed the idea that it was some sort of "brain freeze", since the rest of the query was indeed quite close :).